# What does File "/usr/lib/python3.9/enum.py", line 405, in __getattr__ raise AttributeError(name) from None mean?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio, adc

I have connected an analog joystick to my Raspberry Pi 3B, and I'm trying to get the up down left right movement to map to W A S D. The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import ADC0834
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

BtnPin = 22

def setup():
    # Set the GPIO modes to BCM Numbering
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(BtnPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    ADC0834.setup()

def destroy():
    # Release resource
    GPIO.cleanup()

def loop():
    keyboard = Controller()
    while True:
        x_val = ADC0834.getResult(0)
        y_val = ADC0834.getResult(1)
        Btn_val = GPIO.input(BtnPin)
    # Map joystick input to keyboard keys
        if y_val < 127:
            keyboard.press(Key.W)
            keyboard.release(Key.W)
        elif y_val > 127:
            keyboard.press(Key.S)
            keyboard.release(Key.S)
        if x_val < 131:
            keyboard.press(Key.A)
            keyboard.release(Key.A)
        elif x_val > 131:
            keyboard.press(Key.D)
            keyboard.release(Key.D)
    
    time.sleep(0.2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
    try:
        loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # When 'Ctrl+C' is pressed, the program destroy() will be executed.
        destroy()
```

When the code runs from terminal, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Joystick.py", line 46, in <module>
    loop()
  File "/home/pi/Joystick.py", line 31, in loop
    keyboard.press(Key.S)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/enum.py", line 405, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: S
```

I have downloaded the library pynput through `sudo pip3 install pynput` , and I have also tried to change between upper and lowercase of W A S D in the code. The analog output works as well. I just can't figure out how to map to W A S D properly. Any help is apperciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Key` object does not have attributes for plain letters such as `S`.

If you want to press a plain letter key, use this:

```
keyboard.press('S')
keyboard.release('S')
```